# UI change events being blocked

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom

I have two elements, a paragraph and a button. On clicking the button, the browser should render the text `"Waiting"` with the `p` tag, wait 3 seconds and render the text `"Done"` after. It runs but the text `"Waiting"` is never rendered.

I know this can be solved with `setTimeout` but I am trying to understand why the text `"Waiting"` does not show up at all.

html:

```
<p id="p">Ready</p>
<button id="button">Start</button>
```

Javascript:

```
const pTag = document.getElementById('p');
const button = document.getElementById('button');


button.onclick = () => {
  pTag.innerText = 'Waiting';
  
  syncWaitSeconds(3)

  pTag.innerText = 'Done';
};

function syncWaitSeconds(seconds = 3){
  const start = Date.now();
  
  const time = seconds * 1000
  
  while (Date.now() - start <= time) {
    // waiting 3 seconds
  }
}
```

I am learning Javascript, I want to know why the text was not showing up. As changing the innerText does not return a promise and is synchronous, shouldn't it have happened first, then the wait for 3 seconds and finally the render of the text 'Done' ?

Comment: Unless your HTML elements have `id="p"` and `id="button"` your selectors won't work. On that note please post the HTML too.

Comment: Sorry Dominic, yes. here is the codepen link
https://codepen.io/samroodali/pen/MWBgQmo?editors=1010
html, I have updated in the question

Comment: Excuse me, Samrood Ali for providing another structure in my answer, I was writing it before your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are doing busy-wait, that is, your browser is too busy always comparing those dates and it simply does not get to update the UI. This is a good example for the need of asynchronity. It is not "just" the `innerText` that's not refreshing, it's the whole UI being unresponsive while this busy-wait happens.

This is why you need to do this asynchronously via `setTimeout`. Without `setTimeout`:

```js
const pTag = document.getElementById('p');
const button = document.getElementById('button');


button.onclick = () => {
  pTag.innerText = 'Waiting';
  
  syncWaitSeconds(3)

  pTag.innerText = 'Done';
};

function syncWaitSeconds(seconds = 3){
  const start = Date.now();
  
  const time = seconds * 1000
  
  while (Date.now() - start <= time) {
    // waiting 3 seconds
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<button id="button">My Button</button>
```

With `setTimeout`:

```js
const pTag = document.getElementById('p');
const button = document.getElementById('button');


button.onclick = () => {
  pTag.innerText = 'Waiting';
  
  setTimeout(function() {
      pTag.innerText = 'Done';
  }, 3000);

};
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
<button id="button">My Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks.
But since changing the innerText is synchronous, shouldn't the browser wait for the ui change to be over before executing the rest of Javascript code or this event queued ?

Comment: @SamroodAli no, it shouldn't. Updating the UI is a costly operation, the browser will have to send instructions that will end up being executed by the graphics card. Imagine changing 100 `innerText` values. It would not perform well if all those updates would perform instantly. Much better is to prepare all the jobs to be performed at the UI and execute them once the busy JS operations are done.

Answer (score 0):

I got more explanation on this and sharing it here

The explanation I got was that there are two threads, the JS main thread that handles Javascript and the browser's painting thread that handles UI changes including CSS changes, and there's a thread synchronisation going on between the two.

The task to change to "Waiting" did execute and  painting thread was supposed to handle it but it waited because the JS call stack was not empty. So UI changes from both JS and CSS happens only whenever JS code is not running.

After the syncWaitSecond, the thread rendered both "Waiting" and "Done" but it was so fast that we only see 'Done' or there might be some optimisation in composition step that only 'Done' got rendered but these changes only happened when the JS call stack was empty.

When we do this with setTimeout, the call stack is empty immediately and "waiting" is rendered. After 3 seconds, setTimeout gets back into the stack, executes the code to change the text to 'Done'. this task gets added to queue for the UI thread but the UI thread would again wait for the JS code to complete before painting 'Done'.
it was all interesting stuff and made me learn that theres a lot of stuff in JS and Browser land that I don't know.

what's crazy is if you got blocked JS code, not even CSS changes like changing background colour on hover will work as that's also handled by this painting thread and will wait for the JS to complete.